# Reading in from file in a certain format in C produces seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Currently, I'm trying to read in numbers from a file that represent the solution to a Sudoku Puzzle. The file is supposed to be formatted as 9 numbers, with no spaces between, followed by a newline character, ending after the eighty-first number.

While reading in, I'm using fscanf, I can get it to work with a valid puzzle, but not with one that's not a valid format; those produce a segmentation fault. I tried to check the length of the array, but since it's set to 10 when I declared s, that doesn't catch strings that are too short or too long. am I going about this the wrong way? I'll post the code below.

```
FILE* puzzlefile;
char s[10];
int i=0, j=0, skip;
int form;

//opens the file so we can access the puzzle
puzzlefile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

for (i=0; i<9; i++){
    form = fscanf(puzzlefile, "%s\n",s);
    for (j=0; j<10; j++){
        if (form == 0){
            printf("Invalid format on input. Bad newline.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if(j<9){
            if(s[j] == '1' || s[j] == '2' || s[j] == '3' || s[j] == '4' || s[j] == '5' || s[j] == '6' || s[j] == '7' || s[j] == '8' || s[j] == '9'){
                puzzle[i][j] = (int)(s[j]-'0');
            }
            else{
                printf("Invalid format on input.\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? If so, am I just misusing fscanf()? Or should I be using another type of input function? The files I'm testing include some that follow the format but with letters instead of numbers, one puzzle with an extra number on the first line, one puzzle that has newlines every 5 numbers, and one that is all numbers and no newlines. All of these produce a seg fault.

Comment: for input that require validation, you could do it manually, like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e00103b3fa514696

Comment: @sp2danny Unfortunately, the requirements of this particular program is that it MUST read from a file in this specific format, otherwise I would have considered that. Thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't check `puzzlefile` for `NULL`, you should ensure that the file was opened, in case it wasn't `fopen()` returns `NULL`, so checking the return value of `fopen()` as a very important thing to do.
2. You don't seem to check if `argv[1] != NULL` which would happen if you forget to pass arguments to the program, the consequences would be the program malfunctioning and you will recieve no clue of why.
3. The size of `s` is too small, and it's easy to overflow it, make `fscanf()` aware of how much space is there for the destination string, like this

   ```
   form = fscanf(puzzlefile, "%9s\n", s);
   /*                          ^ 9 characters + '\0' = 10 */
   ```
4. To prevent reading past the end of the string do this

   ```
   for (i = 0 ; s[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   for (i=0; i<10; i++)
   ```

   and the same with the inner loop.
5. It would be much better if you do this

   ```
   if ((s[j] > '0') && (s[j] < 1 + '9'))
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   if(s[j] == '1' || s[j] == '2' || s[j] == '3' || s[j] == '4' || s[j] == '5' || s[j] == '6' || s[j] == '7' || s[j] == '8' || s[j] == '9')
   ```

---

You didn't post the declaration of `puzzle`, it could also be the problem if you are writing after it's end, you should be very careful with bound checking in c because writing past the end of a buffer, doesn not have a defined behavior, and in some situations nothing bad will happen when you test it, and of course the bug will stay silently there until it explodes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the %9s. I didn't know you could do that! However, I'm still getting a seg fault on invalid puzzles after following your advice.

Comment: @RobertCrawford please post the whole `main()`, your code is missing stuff.

Comment: To address your edit, "puzzle" is a global variable, declared as "int puzzle[9][9];" The only reason that I didn't include the rest of the main function is because the project is an exercise in threads. This is pretty much everything in the main function. As long as the data is read in correctly, then the rest will work; it's already been tested. The only problem with the code is when the format isn't handled correctly, which I intend to as I read it in.

Comment: Do not use global variables, specially  in threaded programs, global variables are mean, and yes sometimes they can be an easy solution, but the could cause a lot of issues. And you never check `i < 9` hence you are indeed overflowing `puzzle`. Also, check `argc` to prevent accessing arguments that are not available in `argv`.

Comment: Ok, so today I learned a valuable lesson about not including a space inside the names of files you wish to read in using the command line. However, my program is working on your advice, except under one case: if all numbers are in one line with no newline characters. Any idea why this may be?

Comment: @RobertCrawford Oh! And really, don't ever use spaces in filenames at all, it makes it a lot easier to write scripts and pass them as parameters to programs. Also, use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ungetc.3.html) instead of `fscanf()` and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I've got some end of the semester craziness going on with papers and the like. Anyway, would there be a way to use fgets() that would allow me to check if the file follows a certain format like fscanf() does? From what I tried earlier, fgets() doesn't pick up newline characters for your string, and doesn't check for a certain format...

Comment: @RobertCrawford Yes, using `sscanf()`, you first `fgets()` a line from the file and then `sscanf()` it. But, remember that `scanf()` functions are not for pattern matching so it would not be very robust after all.